# Context, Membership, Etc Null when using MVC on IIS7

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7, routes, nullreferenceexception

I'm sure this must be something simple that I'm missing.

I'm using MVC Routing in my Forms applicaiton for Url Routing.  On most of the forms I access the Context, Membership, etc.

On my dev machine and on IIS6 everything works fine.

I'm just trying to get to work on IIS7 and no luck.  The Routing works as it should, but anytime I try to access the Context or Membership I get a Null Value.  Somewhere along the line while routing, those values aren't getting through.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what did the trick. Add the following attribute to  under

runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Some references:
http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/